# How to determine type of values in a slice of interface{}

Tags: go, reflection, reflect

Consider the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func f(v interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(v).Elem())
    fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(v))
}
func main() {
    var aux []interface{}
    aux = make([]interface{}, 2)
    aux[0] = "foo"
    aux[1] = "bar"
    f(aux)
}
```

The output is:

```
interface {}
[foo bar]
```

How can I determine the type of the elements that are contained in a slice of interface{}, in this particular example I need to know in my function `f` that this slice of interface{} contains `string` values.

My use case is, using reflection, I am trying to set a struct field depending on the type of values my slice of interface{} parameter holds.

Comment: You can use type assertions and reflection, but really: try to avoid using `interface{}` as much as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you pass in is of type `[]interface{}`, so the element type will be `interface{}`. If you want to see what the element types are, you need to reflect on those individually:

```
func f(i interface{}) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(i)
    for i := 0; i < v.Len(); i++ {
        e := v.Index(i)
        fmt.Println(e.Elem().Type())
        fmt.Println(e)
    }
}
```

If you know you will always have a `[]interface{}`, use that as the argument type to make iteration and type checking easier:

```
func f(things []interface{}) {
    for _, thing := range things {
        v := reflect.ValueOf(thing)
        fmt.Println(v.Type())
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't always know that I will have a `[]interface{}` as parameter so the first solution works very well. I have one follow up question though. Given that I know that this slice of interfaces contains strings how can I pack the values in a slice of strings? For this I am trying to set the value of a struct field that is of type []string. I've tried using makeSlice but it fails because the values I want to pack are of type interface{}

Comment: If you know you're looking for specific types, then you should be using type assertions and not reflection. Even if you use reflection, you're still going to have to assert the type to put them into a variable with that specific type.